# logical deduction - A Cipher with Numbers

Tags: cipher

> 44339994666666455533

Can you solve this cipher? I know the repetition of numbers holds some significance, but can't really put a finger on how exactly. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to PSE! I interpreted your plea for help as a clever disguise for the finger clue, but just in case it wasn't: any puzzles posted from somewhere else must, as a minimum, have the source clearly stated. All in all, it's a nice puzzle, happy to have you here. Oh, and do remember to [take the Tour](/tour)!

Answer (score 10):

This short message really needs putting your finger on it.

It says

> HEYGOOGLE

and the lack of white space and punctuation seems to indicate that the cipher was created

> without actually having an old (but famously indestructible) Nokia phone in hand.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like tap code from old phones, using that logic the answer is:

> hey google

process:

> 44=h, 33=e,999=y and so on.